# wordpress Next/Previous post in same category not working

Tags: pagination

I use the following code to get the Next /Previous link in the same category

In localhost, it worked good but in my Cpanel host doesn't good working
Following code: First, get current id post and category and then reserve post by date

In WordPress, I posted articles regularly by time.

I have 20 posts and I want to display next / prev button in all 20 posts but only displays in 4 posts

```
    <?php 
    $post_id = $posts->ID; // current post id
    $cat = get_the_category(); 
    $current_cat_id = $cat[0]->cat_ID; // current category id

    $args = array('category'=>$current_cat_id,'orderby'=>'post_date','order'=> 'DESC');
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    // get ids of posts retrieved from get_posts
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($posts as $thepost) {
        $ids[] = $thepost->ID;
    }
    // get and echo previous and next post in the same category
    $thisindex = array_search($post->ID, $ids);
    $previd = $ids[$thisindex-1];
    $nextid = $ids[$thisindex+1];

    if (!empty($previd)){
    ?>
    <a class="ls-right w3-btn prev"el="prev" href="<?php echo get_permalink($previd) ?>">PreLink</a>
    <?php
    }
    if (!empty($nextid)){
    ?>
    <a  class="ls-left w3-btn " href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextid) ?>">NextLink</a>
    <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to Displays Next/Previous link in same posts category and work correctly for me.

```
<?php


 get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

 // Previous/next post navigation.
 previous_post_link('%link', 'Before', true );
 next_post_link( '%link', 'Next', true );

 ?>
```

And For CSS Styling the "%link" Element I use this code in my functions.php file.

```
  /////Next/Prev post style

  add_filter('next_post_link', 'next_post_link_attributes');
  add_filter('previous_post_link', 'previous_post_link_attributes');

   function next_post_link_attributes($output) {/// Styling next link

     $injection = 'class="ls-left w3-btn"';
     return str_replace('<a href=', '<a '.$injection.' href=', $output);

    }

  function previous_post_link_attributes($output) {/// Styling previous link

   $injection = 'class="ls-right w3-btn prev"';
   return str_replace('<a href=', '<a '.$injection.' href=', $output);

   }
```

**Top code**: I use 2 different functions "**previous_post_link_attributes**" and "**next_post_link_attributes**" Because I want to add different CSS style for nex/pre links

If you want to add the same style to next/pre links you can use one method:

```
add_filter('next_post_link', 'post_link_attributes');
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'post_link_attributes');

function post_link_attributes($output) {
$injection = 'class="my-class"';
return str_replace('<a href=', '<a '.$injection.' href=', $output);
}
```

For more about next / pre link --> [wpcodex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) ,[masternsblog](https://masterns-studio.com/blog/wordpress/add-class-to-wp/) ,[wp-stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17218/how-to-add-css-class-to-previous-post-link-or-get-previous-next-post-link-url)